# How to set image path in apache(php)?

Tags: php

I am trying to read a image file/pdf from my desktop in PHP (LAMP) using following command.

```
 <img src="/home/user/Desktop/scatterplot.pdf" />
```

but there is no output on web page. On right clicking image, i found it is looking for following path.

http://localhost/home/user/Desktop/scatterplot.pdf

How can i set path so that it can be searched within the directroy.

Comment: you can use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']  for absolute path to the directory

Comment: Within which directory do you want it to search? Secondly, a PDF cannot be embedded into an IMG tag, the browser can't render a pdf as it expects an image.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you have to use a relative path to the image. A relative path the document root of your website. It is your browser who is doing the request and it will not be able to access absolute paths on any machine.
You can create a symlink to that folder somewhere in your web application and then create a correct link.

Answer (score 1):

The root is set in the `DocumentRoot` settings in the httpd.conf. You can solve it by creating virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/yourweb"
    ServerName yourweb.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

And then run your web from url

```
http://yourweb.localhost
```

Don't  forget to set the hosts: `/etc/hosts` on Linux, `%WinDir%/System32/drivers/etc/hosts` on Windows. Add this line

```
127.0.0.1       yourweb.localhost
```

You will probably need reset under windows.

Comment: I restarted the server after following your instruction. I got following error mesage: Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Comment: well, you are that webmaster :-) Check your paths. Your example would work if the DocumentRoot was set to `/` and you probably don't want the visitor to roam across your computer. Set the DocumentRoot to something like `/var/www/`, set the link to something like `/files/scatterplot.pdf` and place it to `/var/www/files/scatterplot.pdf` (you don't need to set virtual host in this case)